# How can I read the properties of an object that I assign to the Session in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying my hand at creating a session which stores member information which the application can use to reveal certain navigation and allow access to certain pages and member role specific functionality.

I've been able to assign my `MemberLoggedIn` object to the session in this way:

```
    //code excerpt start...

    MemberLoggedIn loggedIn = new MemberLoggedIn();

    if (computedHash == member.Hash)
    {
        loggedIn.ID = member.ID;
        loggedIn.Username = member.Username;
        loggedIn.Email = member.Email;
        loggedIn.Superuser = member.Superuser;
        loggedIn.Active = member.Active;

        Session["loggedIn"] = loggedIn;
    }
    else if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Incorrect Username or Password."); 
    }

    return View();
```

That works great. I then can send the properties of `Session["loggedIn"]` to the View in this way:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (Session["loggedIn"] != null)
            ViewData.Model = Session["loggedIn"];
        else
            ViewData.Model = null;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

In the Partial View I can reference the session data by using `Model.Username` or `Model.Superuser`.

However, it doesn't seem to work that way in the controller or in a custom Action Filter. Is there a way to get the equivalent of `Session["loggedIn"].Username`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that ASP.Net MVC uses wrappers around the static ASP.Net singletons like Application and Session.  This is to allow code to be decoupled from, and unit tested outside of the ASP.Net pipeline.

From an action filter, use:

```
((MembershipUser)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"]).Username
```

And from inside a controller, use:

```
((MembershipUser)ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"]).Username
```

Comment: I didn't know about ControllerContext. That's cool. I'm more looking for how to get something like ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"].Username to return the Username (a string) of the logged in member.

Comment: ((MembershipUser)ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"]).Username.  Careful that it's not null before you try accessing the username though.

Comment: The part that @quakkels is missing is that he needs to cast the result from `object` to `MemberLoggedIn`.  You might want to edit that into your answer and then it will be even better.

Comment: (MemberLoggedIn)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"].Username does not work in my Action Filter

Comment: ((MemberLoggedIn)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"]).Username; also is erroring.

Comment: What's your action filter method signature?  There should be a parameter passed into OnActionExecuting or OnActionExecuted - the "filterContext" is the name of that variable.

Comment: oh wait... my bad... this works: `string u = ((MemberLoggedIn)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"]).Username;`

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
MemberLoggedIn user = (MemberLoggedIn)HttpContext.Session["loggedIn"];
```

Comment: yikes, `HttpContext.Current`. How about unit testing this? It so much kills the whole ASP.NET MVC thing.

Comment: No!  Don't use HttpContext.Current, that's one of the whole reasons MVC abstracted the ASP.Net contexts.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IPrincipalUserModelBinderInASPNETMVCForEasierTesting.aspx

Comment: This seems like its exactly what I'm looking for. I used it without the '.Current' and it worked exactly as I expected.

Comment: @Darin & @womp - is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @quakkels - that's because there is an instance property of your Controller that is named HttpContext, which is what you're acessing.  The example here is using the static singleton System.Web.HttpContext.Current.

Comment: Yes, you're right; I edited my answer.  As you pointed out, action filters should use `filterContext.HttpContext`.

Comment: This works well. I think this versus the other answer is probably just a matter of style.